# UITableView GridLayout Problems with Reusable UITableViewCells

Tags: ios

I am creating a Grid (spreadsheet) like layout for iPad app using UITableView. I got the grid part working but since I am dynamically adding UILabels to the cells the reusable portion is not working fine. Here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"FundCell"];

    Fund *fund = [funds objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    float labelWidth = 1024 / ([columnNames count] -1 );

    for(NSString *columnName in columnNames)
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, 0, labelWidth, 44)];

        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        label.text = [fund valueForKey:columnName];

        x += label.bounds.size.width;

        [cell addSubview:label];
    }

    x = 0;

    return cell;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Why not use `UICollectionView` instead of creating multiple `UITableView` instances

Comment: I am not creating multiple UITableView instances!!!

Comment: Your code is fine. Have you set cell identifier to @"FundCell"?

Comment: Yes but if I reuse the cells then it gets overlaps as shown in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding new labels in every reuse. You should only add the labels once, store references to them (usually as properties of a custom cell subclass) and just set the text value thereafter.

You may find it easier to define a custom cell in a xib and position your labels there, creating outlets. You can register this for reuse with the table, it will create or dequeue a cell as needed.

Comment: That is true! But I am dynamically creating the uilabels so this can be reused by other view controllers and not depends on the interface builder and outlets. But I will give that a shot! That will be the easiest to make!

Comment: A cell defined in its own nib can be reused wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks! If I have collections different from each other having different columns then do I need to create 5 different nibs/custom cells.

Comment: Depends what's in the columns really, you'll have to decide between one customisable class or separate ones.

Comment: I guess I will go for separate one since the client might decide that they want 5 columns in one and then 10 in the other.